# Why is trying to download a Facebook image link giving me 403?

Tags: php, facebook, http-status-code-403

I saw an image posted on Facebook.  I wanted to run it through an image search system, something akin to Tin Eye.  After doing this many times manually, I wrote a Chrome extension to do it.  It failed, the remote page kept getting 403.  So instead of my extension passing the URL to the search service, I pass it to my own web server figuring I can just download the file then pass the URL to my own server instead.

I got the 403 when I tried as well, but figured throwing in a browser user agent would fix that.  Nope, still 403'ing.  Does anyone know how to grab images from Facebook?  I've no idea what to try next.

Facebook URL I tried: https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/12122627_10153631184244320_8240475011131575646_n.jpg?oh=905919fbb09f3c59af1c73f7c85eb455&oe=5688C900

Passed to this code:

```
<?php

  if (!empty($_REQUEST["url"])) {
    $options = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .
                  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n"
      )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $file = file_get_contents($_REQUEST["url"], false, $context);

  }

?>
```

I tried opening the URL in my browser, it returns an image.  I tried removing the https and requesting it as http, same problem.  No idea now.

EDIT: I just figured maybe those headers weren't enough so I fired up Wireshark and grabbed the headers Chrome actually uses when requesting the image URL and added them, but it made no difference :(

```
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n" .
              "Host: scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net\r\n" .
              "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" .
              "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" .
              "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n" .
              "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36\r\n"
```

Comment: They probably have measures in place that try to stop “bots” from downloading images, and to restrict it to “real” users using “real” browsers as much as possible. Btw., you’re aware that file_get_contents is not cURL, right?

Comment: Ah shoot, sorry I got mixed up.  I was originally using curl then when trying some code I found when searching how to add headers it switched to fgc.